# MAX IF function that refers to other sheet

Tags: excel, macos, if-statement

I have a sheet in my workbook called Group Dashboard. On that sheet I am entering a formula referring to another sheet.

```
=MAX(IF('Worker Dashboard'!C:C=1,'Worker Dashboard'!F:F))
```

I want it to look through all the data in Worker Dashboard. For each line where the value in the C column is 1 (or 1.0), I want it to consider the value in Column F. It should then output the MAX value among the considered values from Column F.

This formula seems to work fine.

However, when I then enter the following:

```
=MAX(IF('Worker Dashboard'!C:C="<1",'Worker Dashboard'!F:F))
```

It just reads 0. The max value should not be 0. Column C in that sheet has values <1 such as 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, etc. If I change the formula to:

```
=MAX(IF('Worker Dashboard'!C:C="<1",'Worker Dashboard'!F:F,-1))
```

Then the output is -1. This makes me think there is an issue with the logic statement:

```
'Worker Dashboard'!C:C="<1"
```

I have also tried variations for other purposes where the logic statement is:

```
=MAX(IF('Worker Dashboard'!B:B="General",'Worker Dashboard'!F:F))
```

However, here too it spits out 0 even though the max is 5.0 for rows where Column B lists General and the value in Row F is considered.

Comment: Use `'Worker Dashboard'!C:C<1` not `'Worker Dashboard'!C:C="<1"`. Are you finalizing the *array* formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Comment: I cringe every time I see an array formula using entire column references. That construction is being forced to calculate over more than two million cells, an astonishing amount for a single formula. I don't know where this idea comes from that, with array formulas, you can arbitrarily reference as many cells as you like beyond the end of your data with no detriment to performance. Unlike e.g. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), array formulas calculate over all cells passed to them, whether technically beyond the last-used cells in those ranges or not.

Comment: XOR LX: Thanks for the feedback. I have noticed that my spreadsheet is incredibly slow to update after each change. I now realize it may be due to these numerous column references. What would be a better way to handle this without the column reference. I don't want to give a set reference because the amount of data rows may change as we add more data. Any ideas on a way to reference just all the rows with data in that column?

Comment: By the way, thanks to Jeeped and pnuts. That fixed my issue. I am very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

There are two points that I've found from your description of the problem.

1. Use `'Worker Dashboard'!C:C<1` not `'Worker Dashboard'!C:C="<1"`. Comparing a true number to the textual representation of that number will work with some functions like the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) but not all. Best to compare numbers to numbers and test to text whenever possible.
2. Your formula looks to be of the *array formula* variety. Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> and not just <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. When entered correctly with CSE, Excel will wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type these in yourself. Once entered correctly, the formula may be copied/filled to new locations with conventional methods like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (aka Fill Down) and the CSE will carry along.